# PHP basic transformation if then else

Tags: php

I wan to convert the following code from this

```
$diff = strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current);
if ($diff < 7200) {
    echo 'Starts soon';
} else if ($diff <= 0) {
    echo 'Started';
} else {
    echo 'Starts';
}
```

to this ?

```
<?= ($current > $row['start']) ? 'Started' : 'Starts';  ?>
```

How can ( if possible ) be written in such way ?

Comment: AFAIK, shorthand for `if else` can't be applied to `else if`

Comment: Your original conditions are bogus, the 'Started' will never be printed because the first condition will always be true if the second one is, and executed instead.

Comment: else if ($diff <= 0)  block will never be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very readable, so I wouldn't use it but here you go:

```
echo ($diff < 7200) ? 'Starts soon': (($diff <= 0) ? 'Started': 'Starts');
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not really pretty, but you can do it like this :

```
<?php
$diff = strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current);
echo ($diff < 7200 ? 'Start soon' : ($diff <= 0 ? 'Started' : 'Starts'));
?>
```

Or

```
<?= ((strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current)) < 7200 ? 'Start soon' : ((strtotime($row['start']) - strtotime($current)) <= 0 ? 'Started' : 'Starts')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

else if can be applied when in else part You add new if.

```
<?= (($diff < 7200) ? "Starts soon" : (($diff <= 0) ? "Started" : "Starts")); ?>
```

Comment: That is not correct. The ternary operator is left associative in PHP, you need an additional pair of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with an `if elseif` statement covering a few lines. It makes it easy to read, easy to follow and easy to see what is happening if you are checking your code later - or more importantly if someone else is reading your code.

Remember, it is always easier to write code than it is to read is.

From the [documents](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
<?php
// on first glance, the following appears to output 'true'
echo (true?'true':false?'t':'f');

// however, the actual output of the above is 't'
// this is because ternary expressions are evaluated from left to right

// the following is a more obvious version of the same code as above
echo ((true ? 'true' : false) ? 't' : 'f');

// here, you can see that the first expression is evaluated to 'true', which
// in turn evaluates to (bool)true, thus returning the true branch of the
// second ternary expression.
?>
```

It's really not too advisable as it is hard to read and easy to mis-read.